# Is every step in a scikit-learn pipeline refitted for each grid-searched hyper-parameter configuration?

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline, grid-search

Assume you have a scikit-learn pipeline with two steps: first, a transformer object (eg, PCA) and, second and last, an object with a predict method (eg, a logistic regression). Suppose that your grid contains four different hyperparameter configurations consisting of two different number of principal components (for PCA) and two different regularization parameters (for logistic regressions).

Is the first object (PCA) fitted 4 times (one for each configuration)? Or, on the contrary, it is fitted two times only: for each number of principal components, fits PCA once and twice the logistic regression. This way seems more efficient and equivalent in terms of results.

I thought that it was the second way, but I got confused by a comment on scikit-learn github (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4813#issuecomment-205185156)

Comment: Yes, it is. For each combination, the supplied model (pipeline here) will be cloned and fitted. You may try using [the caching system of pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#caching-transformers-avoid-repeated-computation) to reduce some duplicate fittings (fitting with same configuration and data), but I am not sure how that works entirely or even if it works with cloned pipelines.

Comment: ^ Maybe that should  be an answer?